# Segmentation fault while convering negative int to binary

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am getting a segmentation fault when running the code below with a negative int value. I am stumped at how to troubleshoot why this is happening.

The goal of this method is to convert a signed into into a binary string representation. This function works for positive numbers but segfaults on negative numbers

Function call:

```
int_to_binary(-1, "00000000000000000000000000000000\0");
```

Src:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_SIZE 33

int int_to_binary(int input, char* output) 
{
  output += BUFFER_SIZE - 1;

  while(input) 
  {
    --output;

    if(input & 1) 
    {
      (*output)++;
    }

    input >>= 1;
   }

  return 0;
}
```

I am only decrementing the pointer when the int is not equal to 0 which would imply that there are still values to convert. Any help on how to debug this in Linux would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The obvious suggestion would be to install and launch [ddd](http://www.gnu.org/software/ddd/)

Answer (score 3):

This code is shouting segfault.

Your buffer is not even a buffer, its a hardcoded and supposedly read-only string that you don't even have a pointer reference from the caller. You shouldn't be writing to it.

And when you shift a signed number its not really a binary shift. `input` will never stop being `-1`.

What you need to do to shift it properly is:

```
input = (unsigned int)input >> 1;
```

Comment: Important point repeated, for emphasis: **You are not allowed to modify string literals! You must treat them as read-only!**

Answer (score 1):

You are likely running into an infinite loop because `input >>= 1` shifting in ones from the left for negative numbers (arithmetic shift). This will cause you to overrun the `output` buffer.

To make sure this is the case you can step through the loop in a debugger and inspect how `input` gets changed by the shifting.

Answer (score 1):

You change the pointer value (`--output`) to point to some other non-well-defined memory location and then you try to change the value at this memory location (`(*output)++`) which causes the segfault.

Answer (score 0):

Try casting `input` to `unsigned int` at the beginning of your function

Comment: [This reference](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/INT34-C.+Do+not+shift+a+negative+number+of+bits+or+more+bits+than+exist+in+the+operand) might help, too.